# How to remove index.php in codeigniter with https://www. in the url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search$ webapp/search/

</IfModule>
```

This code is not working in with https can any help or any solution.

"https://www.royez.com/category/ethnic-wear/kurtas-and-kurtis-97.html" is not working

https://www.royez.com/index.php/category/ethnic-wear/kurtas-and-kurtis-97.html 
working.

Comment: Thank you for helping me I improved the question. I think its perfect now.

Comment: This question is asked lots of time and you can find it simple goolgeling too.Make sure your .htaccess working

Comment: There are lot of questions to remove index.php , But I can't find any solution with https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this question. The problem was that when I was redirecting the website to https the curl function stopped working.Now I rewrite the curl post function and problem is solved now.
Thank you all